# How to get status and song info from iTunes on Mac

Tags: macos

The iPhone has an app that can control iTunes on a Mac, for example play a song. Is it possible to get iTunes status in my program (Objective-c or other language like node.js)? When I play a song I want to receive an event, and when I add a song I want to know what file I added in my program. I tried to find documentation about this but found no result - is there documentation about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, this can be done with Applescript. iTunes is fully scriptable. You can control it, get information about the currently playing media, etc.

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php